# ios Simulator Black Screen

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator

I am beginner in ios development. Initially the code was working properly and shown the output but after addition of more code it gives black screen on Simulator. I have tried [image] but it won't work for me.

Comment: What is your code that is creating problem ?

Comment: Does your app have root view controller?

Comment: Guys there was some problem but finally it is solved. Restarted Xcode and Simulator. Thanks